# Dependency properties with sub properties update master property?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to come up with a solution for the following problem:

I have a DateTimeRange class which contains 3 properties:

- Start: DateTime
- End: DateTime
- Length: Length (=End-Start)

This class is used throughout my project as dependency property on various controls. This values are mutable, for example, if the Start changes, the End will be moved with the same offset (keeping the same Length).

My problem is that in code that listens for updates of the range, does not recieve an event when any of the properties have changed, only when the complete object is replaced.

I want to let the DateTimeRange class notify the user that the whole object has changed when a property is changed, not just one property.

I have tried to make DateTimeRange an immutable struct. But this makes two way DataBinding to any of it's properties impossible.

Does anybody have a suggestion how to do this? IMO this problem is very frustrating, as the same problem happens with Margins for example (you cannot bind to Margin.Left of a control).

Comment: Are you using SL or WPF?

Answer (score 2):

The framework does not really support this requirement. The approach I would take would be to make `DateTimeRange` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, raising the event whenever any of its properties change. On a class that has `DateTimeRange` as a dependency property add / remove handlers for the `INotifyPropertyChanged` as the property changes. Within your handler for this event you can then perform the action you require.

Note, you could make `DateTimeRange` a `DependencyObject`, which would allow you to create two way bindings to its properties.

Comment: could you please clarify on this bit: On a class that has DateTimeRange as a dependency property add / remove handlers for the INotifyPropertyChanged as the property changes. thanks!

Comment: This requires more work for the control using this. Not really what I want, then I need two listeners for the same property changed. (one that listens for changes OF the property and one that listens for changes ON that property)